# Dynamically Create Cloud Run or Function determined by attribute in pub/sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, mapreduce, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I am trying to get a Cloud Run or Cloud Function to start and pull out messages that match its defined ID, for example, if a message with attribute ID 1 is put into the topic, The Cloud Run with ID 1 will take it out, it's important that all messages with attribute 1 go to the same instance.

I understand I could use filters on the subscriptions but I would like to able to easily change the amount of possible ID's, e.g. If I only put messages in the topic with ID's ranging between 0 and 4  then only five instances would be started.[image: Proposed structure diagram]

How would I go about creating something like this? Does Pub/Sub support this sort of functionality?

I know I could create X amount of topics and then put each message into its own topic but that seems like a inefficient way of executing this when there is the attribute system.

Comment: You cannot specify in Pub/Sub to which endpoint send a message based on an attribute. You may need a service between CR and Pub/Sub as a "router". `it's important that all messages with attribute 1 go to the same instance` to what do you refer as Cloud Run instance? Do you mean service? If you actually mean the instance running in Cloud Run, you cannot redirect messages to specific instances

Comment: Also what you describe doesn't sound as you're creating functions/CR services based on messages (as you write in the title) but processing them in already created services. Can you clarify this?

Comment: Ah I may have worded that badly, I want no more than one container per message attribute. I suppose youre right that I would instead like the Cloud Run to poll the pub sub and take out any data that is available for them in there. Like how AWS's SQS would work.

My main issue is getting a cloud run instance to start when there is a message with an attribute that does not already have a running container assigned...

Comment: Have you found solution? if so, can you share as solution?

Comment: @RoopaM sort of, I found another way of doing it that worked for my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not possible, I had to instead, wait for all data for the desired function to be ready before starting the function, I could not have it continually poll and get the correct data.

Therefore the best approach was to put the data into a firestore, then when all the data was ready for the next layer to process it, I would put a message in a pub sub that contained a message ID, this message ID would determine the data that this function would process.

The function would then query the firestore for messages with a property that included the message ID it was given.

I could not find any other work approaches that would give me the result I desired.